# array manipulation in PHP to use in d3 tree layout

Tags: php, arrays, d3.js, tree

hi im a newbie in D3 tree layout so im struggling how I will manipulate my data array to into an array to its desired form please help.........  below is my array from database

```
          Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBTF
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [child_id] => 2
                            [parent_desc] => Perform SPC Data Monitoring using SPC system based control chart
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [child_id] => 3
                            [parent_desc] => Encountered OOC?
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [child_id] => 4
                            [parent_desc] => Encountered OOC?
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [child_id] => 5
                            [parent_desc] => NO
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 4
                            [child_id] => 6
                            [parent_desc] => YES
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 5
                            [child_id] => 0
                            [parent_desc] => Continue next step
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 6
                            [child_id] => 7
                            [parent_desc] => Complete reeling in process reel then stop operation.
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 7
                            [child_id] => 8
                            [parent_desc] => Technician to verify SPC chart to identify the specific actual OOC:
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 8
                            [child_id] => 9
                            [parent_desc] => Technician to perform machine verification and corrective actions based from the specific actual OOC:
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 9
                            [child_id] => 10
                            [parent_desc] => Perform PBFT and check results if sufficient to clear the trend of OOC
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 10
                            [child_id] => 11
                            [parent_desc] => OK?
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 10
                            [child_id] => 12
                            [parent_desc] => OK?
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 11
                            [child_id] => 8
                            [parent_desc] => NO
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 12
                            [child_id] => 13
                            [parent_desc] => YES
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [ocap_id] => 1001
                            [ocap_name] => PBFT
                            [parent_id] => 13
                            [child_id] => 5
                            [parent_desc] => Accomplish SPC OOC RC&CA at computer.
                        )

                )
```

well as you observed i have a parent and children relation.......
what i want is all children array will be inside its parent array  like in this sample of D3 Tree layout https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout   pls help me thank you in advance

Comment: you can use json_encode($yourArrayName);

Comment: i dont have problem in converting it in json data........... the problem is how to manipulate the parent --- children array relation..........